# Navigate back to MainPage Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, xaml, webview, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013

I have a windows phone app that navigates between pages and I use

```
NavigationService.GoBack();
```

to go back to the Mainpage.  All good and works great.

The app is a simple 2 page app and works great under IOS, Android and Windows Phone, but I need to find the correct way to go back to the MainPage in Windows Store Apps using VS2013EX.

I tried

```
Frame.GoBack();
```

but it does not work well due to the fact that my second page is a WebView and if I navigate to another page on the webview, the Frame.GoBack() does not remove the second page but just goes back to the other web page.  Its almost like Frame.GoBack() is just  the webView's go back method.

I tried this code:

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
```

This does bring me back to the MainPage, but I don't think its correct as should I not be removing the current page from the Stack????

Comment: Check this: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-Navigation-sample-dbd7116c/

Comment: The sample code uses Frame.GoBack() so it does not really help answer my question.  Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: add an event handler for `OnNavigatedFrom` in which do the `(WebviewName).NavigateToString("")` and use `this.Frame.GoBack()`.

Comment: not sure what you mean to do as I need the whole page to unload and go  back to the MainPage.xaml and not navigate back on the web view.  Any chance you can explain more.  thanks

Comment: Try to set the property `NavigateToString` to empty string. This property is belongs to Webview object.